# SM3_Basic.IAxisRef.GetAxisRefPointer not working as expected

Tags: codesys, structured-text

Running "CODESYS V3.5 SP16" here, does anyone have the same problem with the method in the title?

```
PROGRAM PLC_PRG
VAR
    itfAxisRef : SM3_Basic.IAxisRef;
    pAxisRefSm3 : POINTER TO SM3_Basic.AXIS_REF_SM3;
END_VAR
```

```
pAxisRefSm3 := itfAxisRef.GetAxisRefPointer;
```

Trying to compile the above throws the following error

```
C0032:  Cannot convert type 'GETAXISREFPOINTER(sm3_basic, 4.10.0.0 (3s - smart software solutions gmbh))' to type 'POINTER TO SM3_Basic.AXIS_REF_SM3'
```

which has me really confused because I've never seen the type `GETAXISREFPOINTER` before and the documentation for `.GetAxisRefPointer` states that it returns `POINTER TO AXIS_REF_SM3`

https://help.codesys.com/webapp/3dvrBKsuKjYfmeP1KzrJnylfstc%2FGetAxisRefPointer;product=SM3_Basic;version=4.9.0.0

As for why I'm trying to use this method, I'm trying to loop through the array of axes in `SM3_Robotics.AXIS_GROUP_REF_SM3` and pass them to `SM3_Basic.MC_ReadStatus` in order to get their individual `SM3_Basic.SMC_AXIS_STATE` (not only the `SM3_Robotics.SMC_AXIS_GROUP_STATE`) for debugging

Is there a better way to achieve the above without using the axes array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GetAxisRefPointer is a Method, try:

```
pAxisRefSm3 := itfAxisRef.GetAxisRefPointer();
```

Comment: ohhhhhh so that's what that error means, that's embarassing, I didn't think of that σ(^_^;)